# Using Redis via BookSleeve. Unknown parameter

Tags: c#, nosql, redis, booksleeve

I'm trying to use redis via C#. For this I selected BookSleeve. But I'm interested that most of the methods (reading/writing) need a parameter: `int db`. The description of this parameter is "The database to operate on". 
When I set `db=0`, then I can see keys using redis-cli.exe typing the command KEYS. If `db != 0`, the keys woudn't be shown.

The question is - What exactly does this parameter mean? I haven't found any information in the web.

Answer (score 8):

The DB parameter is required in order to know for Booksleeve ( Redis ) on which DB to operate (DB's are identified by integer numbers 0 - X).

The equivalent REDIS command to the parameter `db` should be [select](http://redis.io/commands/select).